# Importing all models from a folder in Angular 4

Tags: angular, webstorm

I have a models folder with around 48 class files inside. I want to have all of these classes accessable within a service, and be able to create new instances of that class.

i have tried

```
  import * from '../models'
```

but this does not seem to work.

It has only worked for me if i individually import classes like this.

```
import {Permission} from "../models/permission";
```

How can i import everything from the Models folder?

Comment: Not 100% sure that this will work, have never tested it this way, but you could try `import * as myModels from '../models'` and use like `myModels.Permission`

Comment: Is models file or folder?

Comment: @Und3rTow That was an easy fix haha, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official solution of your problem:

[Barrel](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html)

Comment: That's a cleaner solution. Thanks!

Comment: If only they still include "Barrel" in their glossary!